# Generate a dependency graph for a particular method

Tags: python, code-analysis, call-graph, dependency-graph

I used [pyan](https://ejrh.wordpress.com/2012/08/18/coloured-call-graphs/) to generate a call graph for particular python file as follows

```
$ pyan.py -c backup.py journal.py journalcmd.py links.py --dot | dot -Tpng > backup-use-and-def.png
```

I would like to generate a dependency graph for a particular method of a particular class. The method we are interested in usually calls or may call (in conditional statements) many methods from many other files and they similarly use various methods of this library.

Is there a tool that will draw these relationships without going into external libraries or standard library detail? Just displaying the (possible) calls in the scope of the library we are exploring.